# How to inner join a subset of a field, assign values for two cases and dump the rest

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Trying to figure out how to do this without union-ing three separate queries. There are basically 4 subsets of products in the original data set,

> 1. case when I want to set the 'Product' field as 'CPE',
> 2. case when I want to set the 'Product' field as 'CPE Maintenance',
> 3. Those that have matches in the other table 'Dom_product_buckets', I want to pull in the matches from that table as 'Product' field,
> 4. The leftover entries that dont fit into cases 1,2,3 which I do not want.

```
SELECT customer, 'CPE Maintenance' as Product, sum(amt_eop) as revenue 
   FROM table1
   where pr2 in ('Core CPE' , 'Strategic CPE' ) and pr6 like '%Maintenance%'
   group by product, customer
  UNION
SELECT customer, 'CPE' as Product, sum(amt_eop) as revenue
    FROM table1 where pr2 in ('Core CPE' , 'Strategic CPE' ) and pr6 not like '%Maintenance%'
    group by seg_lvl5_2, product, customer
  UNION
SELECT a.customer, b.product_group as product, sum(amt_eop) as revenue
    FROM table1 A
    inner join dom_product_buckets B
    on A.pr2=b.l2_prod_desc and A.pr3=b.l3_prod_desc
    group by b.product_group,a.customer
```

There are NULLS (products that are not CPE or CPE Maintenance and do not have a match in dom_product_buckets) that I do not care about and do not want in final result set.

Table 1:

```
+------------+-----------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------+
|  customer  |          pr2          |             pr3              |                    pr6                    |  amt_eop  |
+------------+-----------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------+
| Customer a | Strategic Networking  | Internet                     | Internet Dedicated Ethernet (IDE)         | 810010.48 |
| customer b | Strategic Networking  | Internet                     | Internet Ethernet                         | 17.7399   |
| Customer c | Strategic Networking  | Internet                     | Internet Dedicated Access                 | 0         |
| customer d | Strategic Networking  | Ethernet Services            | EVPL - National CPA US                    | 11.99     |
| Customer a | Strategic Networking  | Internet                     | Internet Dedicated Access                 | 500       |
| customer b | Strategic Networking  | Private IP (MPLS)            | Private IP Ethernet - US                  | 0         |
| Customer c | Core Voice Services   | Switched Access              | SWA Flat - Interstate CCL                 | 0         |
| customer d | Other & Miscellaneous | Other Core Svcs              | PICC                                      | 250       |
| Customer a | Strategic Networking  | Private IP (MPLS)            | Private IP Port Ethernet                  | 3000      |
| customer b | Core Voice Services   | Local Voice                  | EUCL                                      | 85        |
| customer d | Core Voice Services   | Domestic LD                  | LD - Monthly Minimum Charge / Spend Level | 0         |
| customer b | Core Voice Services   | Local Voice                  | DTL Basic                                 | 11.99     |
| customer x | Other & Miscellaneous | Other Core Svcs              | Carrier Cost Recovery Charge              | -1189.07  |
| Customer a | Core CPE              | CPE Core Sales               | CPE - Core Sales & Installations          | 164.48    |
| customer b | Core CPE              | CPE Core Sales               | CPE - Core Sales & Installations          | 2.76      |
| Customer a | Core CPE              | CPE Core Maintenance         | CPE - Core Maintenance                    | 0         |
| customer z | Core CPE              | CPE Core Sales               | CPE - Core Sales & Installations          | 2.76      |
| customer b | Strategic CPE         | CPE Strategic Networking     | CPE - Private IP  Equipment Rental        | 0         |
| Customer c | Strategic CPE         | CPE Strategic Networking     | MRP - CPE Branded Maintenance             | 0         |
| customer d | Strategic CPE         | CPE Strategic Communications | CPE - VCE Rental                          | 151.94    |
+------------+-----------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

dom_product_buckets:

```
+--------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------+
|       l2_prod_desc       |         l3_prod_desc         |   Product_Group   |
+--------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------+
| Professional Services    | Advanced Communications      | Advanced Comms PS |
| Professional Services    | Unified communications       | Advanced Comms PS |
| Professional Services    | Advanced Comm Pro Serv       | Advanced Comms PS |
| Strategic Communications | Contact Center Services - IP | CCS IP            |
| Strategic Communications | IP Contact Center            | CCS IP            |
| Strategic Communications | Contact Centers Western      | CCS IP            |
| Strategic Networking     | Internet                     | Internet          |
| Strategic Networking     | Video services               | Internet          |
| Strategic Networking     | Digital Voice                | Internet          |
| Strategic Networking     | Ethernet Services            | Ethernet          |
| Strategic Communications | IP Communications            | IP Comms          |
| Managed Network          | Managed Network Services     | MNS_VNS           |
| Managed Network          | Virtual Network Services     | MNS_VNS           |
+--------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Format your code properly.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help.  For instance, what does the `join` do in the third query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude `NULL` values by doing an exluding join. So instead of using an `inner join` in the third query, try using `left join` like so:

```
SELECT a.customer, b.product_group as product, sum(amt_eop) as revenue
    FROM table1 A
    left join dom_product_buckets B
    on A.pr2=b.l2_prod_desc and A.pr3=b.l3_prod_desc
    where b.product_group is not null
    group by b.product_group,a.customer
```

The other two statements should be fine, since they specify that you want `CPE` or `CPE Maintenance`.